# Pg-promise - Reusable queries that may participate in a transaction/task

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, pg-promise

I am trying to achieve a reuse pattern where query functions **may** receive a parameter trx=tx/task if they are participating in an existing transaction/task, and reuse that tx/task context... otherwise if trx=undefined passed in, creates a new task for the queries. The idea is for the function to be agnostic of whether it is being used singularly, or is participating in a higher-order block transaction.

What I desire (ideally) is a promise-function that will return a task context so that I can write clean like the following (which doesn't work):

```
async function trxRunQueries(trx:ITask<any>|undefined = undefined):Promise<any[]>
{
  if(!trx)
    trx=await db.task(); // if !trx then create new task context from db

  const dataset1 = await trx.many(`select * from tableA`);
  const dataset2 = await trx.many(`select * from tableB`);
  return [dataset1,dataset2];

}
```

However seems like db.task() needs to execute the contextual queries in the cb parameter, but it leaves me hanging & wondering how I can achieve the desired pattern without writing the code out twice -- once with db.task(trx => ) wrapper, and another executing trx.many(...) directly.

I was wondering if it is ok to do something hacky, like below, to achieve this pattern of participating-optionally-in-a-transaction, and will it work (or is it really not a recommended way of doing things) -- or is there a better way that I am not thinking of?

```
async function runQueries(trx:ITask<any>):Promise<any[]>
{
  const dataset1 = await trx.many(`select * from tableA`);
  const dataset2 = await trx.many(`select * from tableB`);
  return [dataset1,dataset2];
}

async function trxRunQueries(trx:ITask<any>|undefined = undefined ):Promise<any[]>
{
  let result:any[]=[];
  try {
    // If trx not passed in the create task context
    if(!trx)
      await db.task(async trx => {result=await runQueries(trx)})
    else
      result=await runQueries(trx);
    return result;
  }
  catch (err) {
    throw(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such pattern is implemented by [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo), which uses event [extend](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:extend) to extend the database protocol with context-agnostic entity repositories.

Comment: Hi Vitaly,... could you be a bit more verbose in explaining how I can use extend() event to allow my query batch function to reuse the existing task/tx if passed in the parameter, or otherwise create a new task for the batch? 

I am having trouble wrapping my head around it... thanks for your patience!

Comment: @AndrewOoi If you follow the pattern shown in the demo, you do not need to pass any context around, it works automatically, through repositories. And the right context is always passed into tasks and transactions automatically as well.